# WSO2 Is 5.0 IWA - 401 HTTP response

Tags: error-handling, wso2, wso2-identity-server

I have enabled IWA on WSO2 IS 5.0 and configured the browser for the same. Now when I try to access the SP through non-domain user , I get browser pop-up to enter the user credentials. Now when I cancel the prompt I get a Apache default error page for 401. 
Is there any way wherein I can configure customize error page for the same? I tried to configure the error-page tag in D[WSO2_IS_HOME]\repository\conf\tomcat\web.xml but this doesn't work for me.

If I configure for an existing general error page like this

```
    <error-page>
    <error-code>401</error-code>
    <location>test/generic-exception-response.jsp</location>
    </error-page>
```

it displays the carbon login page and on encountering 401. On entering the login details here I get the configured error page

I'm sure some security setting is avoiding this to work as expected. Can anybody give me pointers to the solution?

Comment: Same problem, but with Identity Server.  I'd like a catch-all error page with nice messages but also hide what server is under the hood.